# check user logged in Concrete5 5.7

Tags: php, concrete5

How do I load the Concrete5 5.7.4.2 environment in order to check if a user is logged in or registered? I used to do it in Concrete5 5.6 with the following code:

```
<?php
    require 'Slim/Slim.php';

    \Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

    include('helpers/adodb5/adodb.inc.php');
    include('../config/site.php');

    define("DIR_BASE",'..');
    define('C5_ENVIRONMENT_ONLY', true);
    define('REDIRECT_TO_BASE_URL', false);

    $GLOBALS['APP_UPDATED_PASSTHRU'] = true;

    include(DIR_BASE . "/index.php");

    Loader::library('authentication/open_id');

    date_default_timezone_set('America/Caracas');

    $usuario = new User();
    if($usuario->isRegistered()) {
        ///code if is logged in
```

But now I cannot use it with ver 5.7.4.2. The `$usuario` var contains an empty user object. Does it have to do with the namespacing?

Answer (score 2):

In Concrete5 5.7 you can check if the user's logged in via this method:

```
<?php
    $u = new User();
    if($u->isLoggedIn()) {
        echo 'Hello '.$u->getUserName();
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hello Daniel, I already tried that and it did not work. I use `print_r($u)` and I get an empty user object. What can I do?

Comment: Try adding `use Loader;` and  `use User;` at the top of the file and see if that helps.

Comment: Ok Im going to test it

Comment: I got:  Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'Loader' has no effect in C:\wamp

Comment: and:   Warning: The use statement with non-compound name 'User' has no effect in C:\wamp\..

Comment: I think you need to use namespacing, it's pretty rigorously enforced in 5.7. This [document](https://www.concrete5.org/documentation/developers/5.7/working-with-blocks/creating-a-new-block-type/getting-started/php-controller/) should outline the structure your code should follow. If you implement that then the `use` statements should stop throwing errors.

Comment: OK, Im gonna try the namespacing. Something like: namespace Application\Tools\adm;

Comment: Yes, you'll want to follow the rest of the structure detailed in that document as that'll autoload the rest of the classes and do the other init that you'll need.

Comment: Hey Daniel, I tried the namespace but it did not work. What do you think it could be? Thank you

Comment: I can't think of anything else; try a post on the official C5 forums and see if they can help there.

Comment: This is definetly the way to go. This should be the accepted answer.